# Multiply vector by number that rescales to integers - what is the name?

Tags: terminology

What is the name of the number that rescales a set of rational numbers s.t. they are all integers? E.G., 1,000 in the following example.

```
> c(-.11, -.105, -.1) * 1000
[1] -110 -105 -100
```

However, if the first number was .1111, the number is instead 10,000.

```
> c(.1111, -.105, -.1) * 10000
[1]  1111 -1050 -1000
```

It seems like it should be simple enough but I can't think of the right name. I tried to relate it to the significand but that didn't make sense.

Comment: Give it a name. This is math, names count not.

Comment: It's the least common multiple of the denominators.

Comment: Aka the least common denominator.

Comment: When you're multiplying by the least common multiple of the denominators, it's sometimes common to say that you're "clearing denominators".

Comment: Sorry, why is it the LCD? Isn't the LCD of c(-.11, -.105, -.1) 200, not 1000?

Comment: Oh I see, that's the smallest number s.t. all numbers are rational. Got it, cool.